# How to find out, whether a Rails model instance is a singular resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my case I get an instance of a resource and I have to find out, whether it's model class represents a singular or plural resource.

I digged through Rails.application.routes and it's instance variables but did not find any possibility to solve this problem.

Update:

I am using polymorphic_path helpers with anonymous model instances in a gem that includes some modules into models and controllers. The final goal is to provide some automatisms for REST controllers and models and provide pathes / routes of the current model/instance as well as it's ancestors.

My latest attempts looked something like that:

```
Rails.application.routes.instance_variable_get(:@router).instance_variable_get(:@routes).instance_variable_get(:@named_routes).delete_if{|k,v| !k.match(/my_model_name_as_downcased_string_here/)}.values.map{|v| v.instance_variable_get(:@defaults)}.map{|h| h[:action]}
```

In the hope it would bring up action :index for plural models and :show for singular. There MUST be a way to make use of introspection to find out whether a model is a singular one, I simply do not find the catch.

Comment: There's no implicit link between a model and a route, and models could in theory have multiple routes. What problem are you trying to solve, there's probably a nicer solution?

Comment: You should post some code that you've tried and any errors that you've encountered.  It's very hard to tell what you're trying to do with so little information.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find any way to find out, whether a resource is singular or plural, I build something on my own. The most secure way IMHO is to hook into route creation direcly. Here's what I did in case anyone encounters the same problem:

```
# alias :resource method of Rails routing mapper and remember which resourses
# are setup as singular
module ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Resources
  def resource_with_singular_recognizer *res, &block
    Rails.application.instance_variable_set(:@sr, ((Rails.application.instance_variable_get(:@sr) || []).push res.first).uniq)
    resource_without_singular_recognizer *res, &block
  end
  alias_method_chain :resource, :singular_recognizer
end

# define a model wide method :singular_resource? that checks the previously
# setup singular resource flag
module ClassMethods
  def singular_resource?
    Rails.application.instance_variable_get(:@sr).include? self.to_s.downcase.to_sym
  end
end

# include :singular_resource? method into all model classes
module Mongoid::Document
  def self.included base
    base.class_eval do
      extend ClassMethods
    end
  end
end
```

I know :alias_method_chain is not the best choice here, feel free to find a better solution.